# No "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, localhost

After installing Ubuntu 12.10, I tried intalling Metasploit (ruby already installed).

First, I get:

```
[-] Failed to connect to the database: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 7337?
```

Then about 30 seconds later it loads the metasploit console, however after trying:

```
msfupdate
```

I get this:

```
msf > sudo msfupdate
[*] exec: sudo msfupdate

[*]
[*] Attempting to update the Metasploit Framework...
[*]

[-] https://localhost:3790 (note, Metasploit Community
[-] Edition is totally free and takes just a few seconds
[-] to register!)
[-] ERROR: Failed to update Metasploit installation

[-] In order to update your Metasploit installation,
[-] you must first register it through the UI, here:
```

This would be fine, however I cannot access localhost on any ports?! Earlier when I tried installing Utorrent, I couldn't access localhost:8080 so I had to uninstall that.

Every local.host I try to visit returns

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at https://localhost:XXXX.
```

Why can't I do anything?!

Answer (score 2):

The error message explained why:

> [-] Failed to connect to the database: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>   Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 7337?

You don't have a database running and accepting connections on port 7337.

Until you confirm that you have a server running and listening on a particular port, there's no point in trying to connect to that port. Of course it will fail.

Comment: @Seananners `netstat -lnt | grep 7337` is your friend here.

Comment: Thank you David, but how then can I get my database running? Surely Metasploit would have created this during installation?

Comment: What [database back end](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Metasploit/UsingMetasploit#Using_Databases_with_MSF) are you using?

Comment: Currently using Postgres as per installation default.

Comment: Okay, so is Postgres running?